# Как вытащить инфу из html тегов по id?

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, парсер

Есть скрипт  получающий запрос (через `input()`). Далее запрос складывается с заранее заданным url, и в переменную присваивается html код получившейся страницы.

Как из всего  полученного html в дополнительную переменную передать только текст из определённого `<div>` с уникальным `id`?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Beautiful Soup and extracting a div and its contents by ID](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2136267/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобно воспользоваться [beautifulsoup4 пакетом](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), чтобы извлечь инфу из html:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifoulSoup(html)
text = soup.find(id=div_id).get_text()
```